# How to implements Java Memory Model Causality test case 1

Tags: java, concurrency, java-memory-model

I'm studying Java memory model in Java Language Specification 17.4.I want to test causality for understanding java memory model.I find a set of causality in [JMM causality test case](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/unifiedProposal/testcases.html).I implement test case 1, it follows :

```
@JCStressTest
@State
public class CausalityTestCase1 {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    @Actor
    public void actor1(IntResult2 r) {
        r.r1 = x;

        if (r.r1 >= 0) {
            y = 1;
        }
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor2(IntResult2 r) {
        r.r2 = y;

        x = r.r2;
    }

}
```

I used jcstress lib to test this case.r1 == r2 == 1 is impossible,but don't occured.I think my implemention is not corrected, but I don't known how to test.

Comment: The fact that r1 == r2 == 1 is allowed doesn't mean that it will happen.

Comment: jcstress execute the test case  1 million times.I think should occur one time.in addition, I test testcase 2 3 6 7 ，but all dont occur.so  i think my test code implements is error.Thanks you ask my another question,see you again.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running of an Intel architecture, where this racing condition does not occur. VMs can implement a stricter model then what the Java memory model requires, but they are not required to do so. If you used SPARC or ARM, you might discover different outcome. The JMM tries to encompass all these architectures in one model.

Comment: JCStress will inform the compiler to reorder instructions for the sake of causing problems using -XX:+StressLCM and -XX:+StressGCM. So it will increase the likely hood of returning into reordering problems that normally would not be encountered.

Comment: That's however also a recommendation, the compiler does not have to reorder instructions.